# Python - run Excel macro

Tags: python, excel, win32com, vba

I would like to use Python to run a macro contained in MacroBook.xlsm on a worksheet in Data.csv.

Normally in excel, I have both files open and shift focus to the Data.csv file and run the macro from MacroBook. The python script downloads the Data.csv file daily, so I can't put the macro in that file.

Here's my code:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import xl

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

macrowb = xl.Workbook('C:\MacroBook.xlsm')
wb1 = xl.Workbook('C:\Database.csv')
excel.Run("FilterLoans")
```

I get an error,

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0,
>   u'Microsoft Excel', u"Cannot run the macro 'FilterLoans'. The macro
>   may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.",
>   u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

The error states that FilterLoans is not available in the Database.csv file...how can I import it?

Comment: Never used Python, but just a guess: `macrowb.Run("FilterLoans")` ?

Comment: Same here :P I have not used python so try this `excel.Run("MacroBook!FilterLoans")`

Comment: Siddharth's code works, thanks!
@iDevlop - that doesn't work because it tries to run the code on the macrowb.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can't have VBA on a *.csv file. You need the *.xlsm file to be the active workbook. I don't think you need to open the *.csv file at all if your macro know how to find it.

2) Enable VBA module access in your Office Excel:

```
File
options
Trust Center
Trust Center Settings
Macro Settings
Enable VBA access
```

3)I am using this function to run macros:

```
excel.Application.Run("FilterLoans")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try savin the macro to your "Normal" Project and call.

```
excel.Application.Run("Normal.ModuleName.SubName")
```

You can even add the Module to the Normal profile programmatically, but Office doesn't let you do it if you have insufficient access rights.