# Run VBA macro in workbook using Python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlsxwriter

I am a Python beginner so please have some patience.

I wonder is there a way that I can open and run a macro Excel code in a opened workbook before I close it ?

Here is a part of the code :

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Somedata.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
# "save","identifier", "ISIN" "name" are just lists with data

worksheet.write_column(0, 1, save * number_of_rows)
worksheet.write_column(0, 2, identifier * number_of_rows)
worksheet.write_column(0, 3, ISIN)
worksheet.write_column(0, 4, name)


# Set coulmns width

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 15)
worksheet.set_column('B:C', 4)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 13)
worksheet.set_column('E:E', 55)


workbook.close()
```

Thanks:)

Comment: What did you try/consider? Googling "excel xlsxwriter macros" gives the answer right on top - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html.

Comment: "xlsxwriter run vba" also gives plenty of relevant results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python-run-excel-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023990/python-run-excel-macro)

Comment: Thanks ivan_pozdeev and stovfl both of your comments were very helpful. I have managed to run VBA code in my workbook adding the vbaProject.bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link explains it https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html

You have to extract vbaProject.bin file and than add it to the XlsxWriter workbook using the add_vba_project() method:

workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')